# creating "radar chart" (a.k.a. star plot; spider plot) using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, radar-chart

I want to create a plot like the one below:

[image]

I know I can use the [`radarchart`](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=fmsb:radarchart) function from `fmsb` package. I wonder if `ggplot2` can do so, using polar coordinate? Thanks.

Comment: since ggplot2 gives me better control on plot title, x-y scale labels, and even doing facet, I need to do the 30+ radar plots and I want to show them in 1 page, and this help me better understand how ggplot2 works

Comment: You can do all that with base graphics. par(mfrow=c(5,6)) and there's your 30 (tiny tiny) plots on one page. What's wrong with 'title("Hello")' for plot titles? Sometimes time spent understanding ggplot2 is better spent getting on with it with base graphics....

Comment: I think it is a legitimate question to want to do this in ggplot2

Answer (score 10):

First, we load some packages.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
```

Here are the data from the radarchart example you linked to.

```
maxmin <- data.frame(
  total  = c(5, 1),
  phys   = c(15, 3),
  psycho = c(3, 0),
  social = c(5, 1),
  env    = c(5, 1)
)
dat <- data.frame(
  total  = runif(3, 1, 5),
  phys   = rnorm(3, 10, 2),
  psycho = c(0.5, NA, 3),
  social = runif(3, 1, 5),
  env    = c(5, 2.5, 4)
)
```

We need a little manipulation to make them suitable for ggplot.

Normalise them, add an id column and convert to long format.

```
normalised_dat <- as.data.frame(mapply(
    function(x, mm)
    {
      (x - mm[2]) / (mm[1] - mm[2])
    },
    dat,
    maxmin
))

normalised_dat$id <- factor(seq_len(nrow(normalised_dat)))
long_dat <- melt(normalised_dat, id.vars = "id")
```

<del>ggplot also wraps the values so the first and last factors meet up.  We add an extra factor level to avoid this.</del> This is no longer true.

<del>levels(long_dat$variable) <- c(levels(long_dat$variable), "")</del>

Here's the plot.  It isn't quite the same, but it should get you started.

```
ggplot(long_dat, aes(x = variable, y = value, colour = id, group = id)) +
  geom_line() +
  coord_polar(theta = "x", direction = -1) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

[image]
Note that when you use `coord_polar`, the lines are curved.  If you want straight lines, then you'll have to try a different technique.

Comment: Had someone managed to make the lines straight? (PS to Richie: Nice solution! Can you also comment on why my first and last factors don't meet up, even though there's no `""` level there?)

Comment: @Anton It seems that the behaviour of `ggplot2` has changes since I wrote this answer.  (There was a pretty big rewrite somewhere around v0.9.) I've updated the code so it works again.  I can't see an obvious way of straightening the lines or of making the start and end points match up.  I thought that `geom_path` would do the latter, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7):

I spent several days on this problem and in the end I decided to built [my own package](https://github.com/region-spotteR/PrepPlot) atop of `ggradar`. The core of it is an improved version of @Tony M.'s function:

```
CalculateGroupPath4 <- function(df) {
   angles = seq(from=0, to=2*pi, by=(2*pi)/(ncol(df)-1)) # find increment
   xx<-c(rbind(t(plot.data.offset[,-1])*sin(angles[-ncol(df)]),
               t(plot.data.offset[,2])*sin(angles[1])))
   yy<-c(rbind(t(plot.data.offset[,-1])*cos(angles[-ncol(df)]), 
               t(plot.data.offset[,2])*cos(angles[1])))
  graphData<-data.frame(group=rep(df[,1],each=ncol(df)),x=(xx),y=(yy))
  return(graphData)
}
CalculateGroupPath5 <- function(mydf) {
   df<-cbind(mydf[,-1],mydf[,2])
   myvec<-c(t(df))
   angles = seq(from=0, to=2*pi, by=(2*pi)/(ncol(df)-1)) # find increment
   xx<-myvec*sin(rep(c(angles[-ncol(df)],angles[1]),nrow(df)))
   yy<-myvec*cos(rep(c(angles[-ncol(df)],angles[1]),nrow(df)))
   graphData<-data.frame(group=rep(mydf[,1],each=ncol(mydf)),x=(xx),y=(yy))
   return(graphData)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(CalculateGroupPath(plot.data.offset),
                              CalculateGroupPath4(plot.data.offset),
                              CalculateGroupPath5(plot.data.offset), times=1000L)
Unit: microseconds
expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq      max neval
CalculateGroupPath(plot.data.offset) 20768.163 21636.8715 23125.1762 22394.1955 23946.5875 86926.97  1000
CalculateGroupPath4(plot.data.offset)   550.148   614.7620   707.2645   650.2490   687.5815 15756.53  1000
CalculateGroupPath5(plot.data.offset)   577.634   650.0435   738.7701   684.0945   726.9660 11228.58  1000
```

Note that I have actually compared [more functions in this benchmark](https://github.com/region-spotteR/MyDocuments/blob/master/spider_plot_functions.R) - among others functions from `ggradar`. Generally @Tony M's solution is well written - in the sense of logic and that you can use it in many other languages, like e.g. Javascript, with a few tweaks. However `R` becomes much faster if you vectorise the operations. Therefore the massive gain in computation time with my solution.

All answers except @Tony M.'s have used the `coord_polar`-function from `ggplot2`. There are four advantages of staying within the cartesian coordinate system:

1. It allows you to transport your solution also to other plotting packages, e.g. `plotly`.
2. Everybody who has some understanding of the standard cosinus and sinus-function can comprehend how the data transformation works.
3. You can extend and customise the plot like you want - hell, you can use it with any plotting package available in R!
4. You do not need to load *any* except your plotting-package. However it mostly makes sense to rescale your data e.g. with Hadley's `scales`-package.

[image: One possible implementation]

*If like me you know nothing about how to do radar plots when you find this thread*: The `coord_polar()` might create good looking radar-plots. However the implementation is somewhat tricky. When I tried it I had multiple issues:

1. The first issue with this approach is that the lines do not stay
   straight.
2. The `coord_polar()` does e.g. not translate into plotly.
3. The polar coordinate system makes detailed customisation tricky, because annotations and other features will get thrown into the polar coordinates as well.

This guy here made a [nice radar-chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579767/add-unit-labels-to-radar-plot-and-remove-outer-ring-ggplot2-spider-web-plot-co) using `coord_polar`.

However given my experiences - I rather advise against using the `coord_polar()`-trick. Instead if you are looking for an 'easy way' to create a static ggplot-radar, maybe use the great `ggforce`-package to draw circles of the radar. No guarantees this is easier than using my package, but from adaptility seems neater than `coord_polar`. The disadvantage here is that e.g. `plotly` does not support the ggforce-extention.

EDIT: Now I found nice example with ggplot2's coord_polar that revised my opinion a bit.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a non polar coordinate version, I think the following function will help:

```
###################################
##Radar Plot Code
##########################################
##Assumes d is in the form:
# seg  meanAcc sdAcc   meanAccz sdAccz meanSpd   sdSpd   cluster
# 388  -0.038   1.438   -0.571  0.832  -0.825   0.095       1
##where seg is the individual instance identifier
##cluster is the cluster membership
##and the variables from meanACC to sdSpd are used for the clustering
##and thus should be individual lines on the radar plot
radarFix = function(d){
  ##assuming the passed in data frame 
  ##includes only variables you would like plotted and segment label
  d$seg=as.factor(d$seg)
  ##find increment
  angles = seq(from=0, to=2*pi, by=(2*pi)/(ncol(d)-2))
  ##create graph data frame
  graphData= data.frame(seg="", x=0,y=0)
  graphData=graphData[-1,]



  for(i in levels(d$seg)){
    segData= subset(d, seg==i)
    for(j in c(2:(ncol(d)-1))){
      ##set minimum value such that it occurs at 0. (center the data at -3 sd)
      segData[,j]= segData[,j]+3

      graphData=rbind(graphData, data.frame(seg=i, 
                                            x=segData[,j]*cos(angles[j-1]),
                                            y=segData[,j]*sin(angles[j-1])))
    }
    ##completes the connection
    graphData=rbind(graphData, data.frame(seg=i, 
                                          x=segData[,2]*cos(angles[1]),
                                          y=segData[,2]*sin(angles[1])))

  }
  graphData

}
```

If you are plotting by cluster or group you can then use the following:

```
radarData = ddply(clustData, .(cluster), radarFix)
ggplot(radarData, aes(x=x, y=y, group=seg))+
  geom_path(alpha=0.5,colour="black")+
  geom_point(alpha=0.2, colour="blue")+
  facet_wrap(~cluster)
```

This should work with the following data sample:

```
   seg  meanAccVs sdAccVs meanSpd sdSpd cluster
  1470     1.420   0.433  -0.801 0.083       1
  1967    -0.593   0.292   1.047 0.000       3
  2167    -0.329   0.221   0.068 0.053       7
  2292    -0.356   0.214  -0.588 0.056       4
  2744     0.653   1.041  -1.039 0.108       5
  3448     2.189   1.552  -0.339 0.057       8
  7434     0.300   0.250  -1.009 0.088       5
  7764     0.607   0.469  -0.035 0.078       2
  7942     0.124   1.017  -0.940 0.138       5
  9388     0.742   1.289  -0.477 0.301       5
```

[image: Radar plot]

Answer (score 4):

I came across this great library which give perfect, ggplot-compatible spider plots :

https://github.com/ricardo-bion/ggradar

Very easy to install and to use, as you can see on the github:

```
devtools::install_github("ricardo-bion/ggradar", dependencies=TRUE)
library(ggradar)

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
library(scales)
library(tibble)

mtcars %>%
     rownames_to_column( var = "group" ) %>%
     mutate_at(vars(-group),funs(rescale)) %>%
     tail(4) %>% select(1:10) -> mtcars_radar

ggradar(mtcars_radar)
```

[image]

Comment: How can I rescale by group? The case you present is to rescale in terms of the dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer that almost does it in ggplot.

I do nor claim anything more than putting the example here, it is based on what Hadley showed here https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/516

All I did was use deployer/tidyr instead and choose only 3 cars for simplicity

the issues still pending are
1) the last and first point are not connected, this is obvious if you see the coord_polar as a wrapping of the traditional x axis. There is no reason why they should be connected. But that is how radar charts are normally shown
2) to do that you need to add a segment manually between those 2 points. A little manipulation and a few more layers should do it. I will try to work on it if I have some time

```
library(dplyr);library(tidyr);library(ggplot2)
#make some data
data = mtcars[c(27,19,16),]
data$model=row.names(data)

#connvert data to long format and also rescale it into 0-1 scales
data1 <- data %>% gather(measure,value,-model) %>% group_by(measure) %>% mutate(value1=(value-min(value))/(max(value)-min(value)))

is.linear.polar <- function(coord) TRUE
ggplot(data1,aes(x=measure,y=value1,color=model,group=model))+geom_line()+coord_polar()
```