# radar/spider plot in R

Tags: r, plot, radar-chart

I'd like to reproduce something like this plot in R, maybe a little simpler:

http://macroblog.typepad.com/.a/6a00d8341c834f53ef017eea036eda970d-popup

The relevant command seems to be stars, and the closest example from the stars command help seems to be

```
stars(mtcars[4:6, 1:5], 
      locations = c(0,0), 
      radius = FALSE, 
      key.loc=c(0,0), 
      main="Motor Trend Cars", 
      lty = 2)
```

but I'd like

1. control over color and thickness of lines,
2. extend rays beyond the edges,
3. include "grid lines" to show distance from origin.

Suggestions?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614433/creating-radar-chart-a-k-a-star-plot-spider-plot-using-ggplot2-in-r) explains how to make radar charts with [ggplot](http://docs.ggplot2.org/).

Comment: @Lenwood:  Thanks a lot.  That led me to me to the fmsb package, which works.  This example needs some tweaking, but it makes the point:  library("fmsb") radarchart(mtcars[4:8,1:5], maxmin=FALSE, centerzero=TRUE)