# Change the circumferential radial grid segment lines color in the radial.plot function. Plotrix

Tags: r, plot, radial, plotrix

I have two datasets which contain `values` for a radial plot and `colors` for the radial grid lines of this plot.

First dataset:

```
#data 1
values  <- c(0.179615044,  0.011908401, -0.342792441,  -0.154263864,
           -0.251553369, -0.234413350,   0.150411419)
colors <- c("black", "black", "red", "red", "red", "black", "black")
```

Second dataset:

```
#data 2
values  <- c(0.88582075,  0.80089077,  0.79452764,  0.77835694, -0.06816896, 0.24024556, -0.02023557, 
              0.28804668, -0.88184648,  0.93711689)


colors <- c("red",  "red",   "red",   "red", "black", "black", "black", "black", "red",   "red")
```

When I make the radial plots with the following function, I get plots with either colored circular grid lines or non colored circular grid lines. Both plots have the correct radial grid lines colored red.

```
library(plotrix)

#plotrix radial plot
radial.plot(values, grid.col=colors, rp.type="p")
```

How do I get the radial grid lines the get colored and not the circular grid lines? Is `grid.col` the wrong argument the use here?

correct image from dataset 1 (black circular grid + highlighted radial grid lines):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p66Mt.png

incorrect image from dataset 2 (red circular grid + highlighted radial grid lines):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzchS.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a bug in the `radial.plot` code. The new code fixes this problem and only colors the radial segment lines.

For the code: https://github.com/kroeliebuschie/radial.plot/blob/master/radial.plot.R

A new argument (`seg.col`) specifies the radial segment lines.

```
#seg.col specifies the line colors
radial.plot(values, seg.col=colors, rp.type="p")
```

**edit**

The circumferential lines can be changed now. Jim Lemon has added this feature and has called it `grid.col`

see link: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/plotrix/docs/radial.plot

Answer (score -1):

Try the `line.col` argument like this:

```
#data 1
values1  <- c(0.179615044,  0.011908401, -0.342792441,  -0.154263864,
           -0.251553369, -0.234413350,   0.150411419)
colors1 <- c("black", "black", "red", "red", "red", "black", "black")

#data 2
values2  <- c(0.88582075,  0.80089077,  0.79452764,
              0.77835694, -0.06816896, 0.24024556, -0.02023557,
              0.28804668, -0.88184648,  0.93711689)


colors2 <- c("red",  "red",   "red",   "red", "black",
             "black", "black", "black", "red",   "red")

library(plotrix)

#plotrix radial plot
radial.plot(values2, line.col = colors2, grid.col = "black", rp.type = "p")
```

This generates the image below:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Dear SlowLearner, I actualy mean the lines that run from the center of the circle to the outside. they need to look like this:
http://i.imgur.com/5e9mJys.png

And the circular lines need to stay black and not red:
http://i.imgur.com/NRFPetY.png

Comment: Radial and not concentric huh? I did misread your question, apologies.

Comment: No, I do not. I experimented using `ggplot`, which allowed me to changes the colours freely but I ended up with curved lines as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614433/creating-radar-chart-a-k-a-star-plot-spider-plot-using-ggplot2-in-r).