# R - ggplot2: coord_radar not working with geom_rect or annotate('rect')

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with a similar issue that have been discussed here: 
[ggplot - connecting points in polar coordinates with a straight line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276773/ggplot-connecting-points-in-polar-coordinates-with-a-straight-line)
and
[ggplot2: connecting points in polar coordinates with a straight line 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562128/ggplot2-connecting-points-in-polar-coordinates-with-a-straight-line-2)

I wanted straight line with `coord_polar` and the function `coord_radar()` from the `ggiraphExtra` package nearly got me where I wanted to be, i.e. (from a previous response see link 2 above)

```
iris %>% gather(dim, val, -Species) %>%
  group_by(dim, Species) %>% summarise(val = mean(val)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(dim, val, group=Species, col=Species)) + 
  geom_line(size=2) + ggiraphExtra:::coord_radar()
```

However, I would like to add background colour to this plot using annotate('rect') (or geom_rectangle); but when I do:

```
 iris %>% gather(dim, val, -Species) %>%
    group_by(dim, Species) %>% summarise(val = mean(val)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(dim, val, group=Species, col=Species)) + 
    geom_line(size=2) +
    annotate("rect", xmin=0, xmax =2.5 , ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha=0.3, fill="#C77CFF")+
    annotate("rect", xmin=2.5, xmax =4.5 , ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha=0.3, fill="#619CFF")+
    ggiraphExtra:::coord_radar()
```

I get the following error message:
    ``` Error in ``$<-.data.frame ```(``` *tmp*``, "r", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1 ```

This error is a bit obscure to me, I'm not sure what to do with it. Note that the same code with `coord_polar` works just fine. See here:
[polar coord with coloured background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BlCP.png)

Any insights would be much appreciated. Apologies if this is resolved somewhere else, I'm pretty sure I've reviewed all the questions about this topic.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dunno where the error comes from and I [guess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590154/r-ggplot2-connecting-points-in-polar-coordinates-with-a-straight-line#comment38398337_24594083) it's not easy to debug. However, why not just use polygons:

```
p <- iris %>% gather(dim, val, -Species) %>%
    group_by(dim, Species) %>% summarise(val = mean(val)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(dim, val, group=Species, col=Species))
annotPolar <- list(
  annotate("rect",xmin=0, xmax =2.5 , ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha=0.3, fill="#C77CFF"),
  annotate("rect",  xmin=2.5, xmax =4.5 , ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha=0.3, fill="#619CFF"),
  coord_polar()
)

lst <- list(
   p + 
    geom_polygon(size=2, fill=NA, show.legend = F) +
    geom_line(size = NA) +
    guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 2))) + 
    annotPolar +
    ggtitle("polygon"),
  p + 
    geom_line(size=2) +
    annotPolar + 
    ggtitle("line"), 
  p + 
    geom_line(size=2) +
    ggiraphExtra:::coord_radar() +
    ggtitle("radar")
)
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs=lst, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works well indeed. I'm not entirely sure to understand why polygons work but line won't do.