# How to combine scatter plots with polar charts?

Tags: python, r, scatter-plot, polar-coordinates, radar-chart

I have a matrix where each row is a case and each column is an attribute, it is a numerical value that the larger it is the greater the relationship of that case to the attribute. This is an example of a matrix with 3 cases and 5 attributes:

```
  A B C D E
1 2 3 3 2 0
2 0 0 0 5 5
3 0 0 0 10 0
```

I try to make a chart using `R` or `Python` that combines the scatter plots and the polar charts. This way, in this specific case the chart would have a pentagon or circle shape, being each vertex or tick an attribute, while there would be three points (each case) that would be positioned according to the distribution of its attributes. This is the result that should be returned:
[image]

Is there any way to generate a graph similar to this one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [creating "radar chart" (a.k.a. star plot; spider plot) using ggplot2 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614433/creating-radar-chart-a-k-a-star-plot-spider-plot-using-ggplot2-in-r)

Comment: No, in my case I need each case to be represented as a single point and not to appear as many times as it has attributes.

Comment: Can you please clarify how the points are to be drawn? In this trivial case it seems you want to plot the midpoint between the two highest attributes. This is easy enough when the attributes are adjacent, but what if `D` and `B` were the highest?

Comment: I want the midpoints regardless of whether they are in adjacent areas. It would be like drawing a plane with the different points on each of the axes and using the center of it as the point to draw.